# Finding the Limit of (1+1/n)^n as n->infinity using Python/Numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to use Python to plot how the limit (1+1/n)^n as n->infinity [will go towards `e` at large n](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit%20(1%2B1%2Fn)%5En%20as%20n-%3Einfinity).

Why is the plot going towards 1 instead of e?

```
n = np.arange(0,10000,1)
f = lambda x: np.power(1 + (1/x), x)
plt.plot(n,f(n))
```

[image]

Comment: In 1/x, change 1 to 1.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in this line:

```
f = lambda x: np.power(1 + (1/x), x)
```

when x is an int so 1/X will always be 0, do

```
f = lambda x: np.power(1 + (1.0/x), x)
```

Comment: Why does using `np.float(x)` give an error? ie. `lambda x: np.power(1 + 1/np.float(x), x)`

Comment: Error is `TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars`

Comment: well you donr need to do np.float. just to clarify- np.float try to convert an int or a string but you pass it a whole array (x is the whole array not a single number from it, numpy just knows that if the arguments that are passed to `np.power` are arrays, it executes the method  on each element in the array)